# will Indexes be followed with these queries

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I'm making a customer table where I need 4 fields in Indexes.
This is the table structure.

id, userName, status, email, password, fullName, joinDate
(id is autoIncrement and primary key)

The 4 fields in Index are:
userName, status, email, password

The queries I need to run are:

```
select id from table where status='active' and email='emailId' and password='pass' limit 1

select id from table where userName='user' and status='active' limit 1

select fullName from table where id='123' limit 1
```

I want to know if all these queries will follow indexes or not?
If not how can I change the structure so that indexes are followed? I'm using mysql and php.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'following the indexes'? If you want to be sure of sorted data you need to specify the sort order in the query: `select * from table order by userName asc`, for example.

Comment: Easy enough to find out for yourself: use EXPLAIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html)

Comment: By follow I meant if Indexes will be used in all 3 queries. Indexes are followed left to right, and in first query, I'm skipping the first column in index (userName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educated guess is "No", "Yes", and "No", in that order. But guesswork is silly if you have [tools that answer the question and measure the performance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

> how can I change the structure so that indexes are followed?

This is perfectly backwards. Database structure is essentially your public API. Don't change the structure; change the indexes.

Here are your queries, and indexes that are likely to work well. (You're not limited to a single index. But don't trust "likely to work well"; measure with EXPLAIN.)

```
select id 
from table 
where status='active' 
  and email='emailId' 
  and password='pass' limit 1;

create index on table (status, email, password);
```

This query (above) probably won't use the existing index, because the first column--userName--isn't used in the WHERE clause.

```
select id 
from table 
where userName='user' 
  and status='active' limit 1;
```

The existing index *should* be used for this query, as long as you've listed the columns in the index in their actual order. (The two columns in the WHERE clause match the first two columns in the index.) Verify with EXPLAIN.

```
select fullName 
from table 
where id='123' limit 1;
```

The column "id" is the primary key; it already has an index.

It looks like you just "need" to add an index on {status, email, password}.

[MySQL multiple column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes your indexes are good. i like to use php to validate some of the fields as its just one field query. but you should consider changing status to a digit tinyint(1) or char(1) and use 1 = active, 2 = not active, 3=disabled, 4=ban

```
select id,status,password from table where email='emailId' limit 1

$db_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // $db->num_rows;

if($row['status']=='active' &&  $row['password']==$pass && $db_rows==1){do stuff}

select id,status from table where userName='user' limit 1

if($row['status']=='active' && $db_rows==1){do stuff}

select fullName from table where id='123' limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this idea. Keep the current indexes and create another single column index on userName That can work I think.